# phpredis will not install on CentoOS Because of PHP-Devel conflict

Tags: php, centos, phpredis

I have been trying to get phpredis installed on a live box however I am encountering an issue when trying to install PHP-Devel. When running the following command:

> yum --enablerepo=remi install php-devel

I get the following result:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 4.4 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
panopta                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |  951 B     00:00     
remi                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 1.1 MB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.4.38-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.38-1.el6.remi for package: php-devel-5.4.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-devel-5.4.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.38-1.el6.remi
           Installed: php-cli-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.4-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-cli-5.4.37-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.38-1.el6.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I realized that the versions are off so I tried the follpwing command:

> yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-devel

and

> yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php-devel

To no avail. Since I'm not a command line expert, it's hard for me to decipher what this means and how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use centos, but from reading the log and looking at the repo it appears you have `php-cli` installed from `remi-test`. Try something like: `yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-devel` or try removing php and install from one of the `remi-php55` or `remi-php56` repos depending on what version you want.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I gave that a go and ended up with the same result. `Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Installed: php-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(x86-64) = 5.5.4-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6`
I can't remove PHP, it's a live API :-/